# How to configure Smtp based Email setup in Luman laravel?

Tags: php, smtp, laravel-5.3

Hi am new to luman laravel framework.I have doubt,How to configure Smtp based Email setup in Luman laravel?.Actually i did something based on some online tutorial but am not sure its correct or not.

My .end file setup

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=example
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

my mail controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailer;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class mailcontroller extends Controller {
    public function mail()
    {


 Mail::raw('Text', function ($message)
 {
            $message->to('sakthissnite@gmail.com');
 });


    }

}
```

my routes.php file

```
 $app->post('mail','mailcontroller@mail');
```

But i got error like:

> **Fatal error**:  Class
>   'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider' not found in
>   **/var/www/io.tachyloans.com/public_html/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php**
>   on line **163**

What i did wrong, please help me  or prefer any good tutorial for this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you see this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-52-mail-not-working

Comment: Why don't you fill MAIL_USERNAME,   MAIL_PASSWORD fields

Comment: Where you asked in mail controller or .env? @ashanrupasinghe

Comment: you can try in your mail controlled,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you?
**Include the Mail libs:**

```
composer require illuminate\mail
```

**uncomment lines in bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->register('App\Providers\AppServiceProvider'); 
$app->withFacades();
```

Comment: Ya , while i install the composer require illuminate\mail
i got an error like  **Using version ^5.4 for illuminate/mail
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/mail v5.4.13
satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.2.45].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.**

Comment: Ya , i have already  ** $this->app->singleton('mailer', function ($app) {
        $app->configure('services');
        return $app->loadComponent('mail', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'mailer');
        });**

Comment: can you try `composer require illuminate/mail:5.1.*` and `composer require illuminate/mail:5.2.*` any one

Comment: Thank you man , its work like charm,you are awesome.you saved my day.